# I can't check if the SQL Query return a result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to check if my SQL query returned a result, and if everything is working well..

I'm doing that to validate one INSERT Query.

```
    $insert = "INSERT INTO offers (status, description logo) VALUES 
                '" . safe($add['status'][$key]) . "', 
                '" . safe($add['description'][$key]) . "',
                '" . safe($add['logo'][$key]) . "')";

$send = db_query($insert, '+');
```

The **db_query($insert, '+')** comes from a switch statement that i created, to not repeat the same thing over and over again:

```
    case '+':
    while ($resultset = mysql_fetch_row($q)) {
        $val[] = $resultset[0];
    }
    break;
```

To validate my Query, i use this:

```
    if(!$send){
     echo 'something went wrong';
   } else {
    echo 'everything is ok';
}
```

But it show me the same message "everything is ok", even when i put something wrong on my Query:

```
$insert = "INSET INTO offers (statOs, description logo) VALUES 
            '" . safe($add['status'][$key]) . "', 
            '" . safe($add['description'][$key]) . "',
            '" . safe($add['logo'][$key]) . "')";
```

How can i fix that?

Comment: An `INSERT` statement doesn't return rows. You can check, how many rows were affected.

Comment: You are also missing a comma between description and logo, and mis-spelt status in the second code.

Comment: `INSET INTO offers`? No, don't tell me you're actually using this. A typo for sure, right? `INSERT INTO offers` or is that part of the intentional?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` during development if you want to check for errors.

Comment: Of course it was intentional

Comment: That's what I thought. Just (double) checking ;-)

Comment: It makes not much sense to ask about code that you don't show and which is not obvious. And if you don't want to repeat yourself too much, use a more modern database client API than `mysql_*` which does not offer resultset iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An INSERT statement doesn't return rows. You can check, how many rows were affected.
You can use

```
$rows = mysql_affected_rows();
```

See [PHP manual, mysql_affected_rows()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) and please look at the red box and stop using the old mysql_* functions. Consider moving to mysqli or PDO.